# Exposing MoneyFields in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some Django models that use `djmoney.models.fields.MoneyField`. This stores data like "US$1,000.00".

I'm trying to expose this via an API with [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) directly in Django's admin with a custom view like:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import serializers

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def changelist_view_api(self, request, extra_context=None):

        cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
        base_queryset = cl.get_queryset(request)

        fieldsets = self.get_fieldsets(request)

        class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

            class Meta:
                model = self.model
                fields = all_fields

        class ModelAdminListAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
            queryset = base_queryset
            serializer_class = ModelSerializer

            name = '%s List API' % self.model._meta.verbose_name.title()

            def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

        view_handler = ModelAdminListAPI.as_view(queryset=base_queryset, serializer_class=ModelSerializer)
        return view_handler(request, extra_context, format=_format)
```

This works well, with the only exception that it chokes on these special MoneyField instances. With one of these in the field list, this view returns the exception:

```
  File "~/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 43, in list
    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
  File "~/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 761, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "~/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "~/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 679, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "~/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 679, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "~/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 530, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "~/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1148, in to_representation
    value = decimal.Decimal(str(value).strip())
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

Digging into DRF's internals, it appears it's treating the MoneyField as a DecimalField, since that's what it inherits from. However, djmoney also creates another CharField called `*_currency` that stores the currency denomination (e.g. "USD"). Then, when you request the logical value for the money field, it combines the decimal and currency values into the format "".

I think DRF is running into a problem where it's trying to interpret this value as a decimal.

Is this a bug in DRF or do I have it misconfigured? How do I allow DRF to properly interpret MoneyField values?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, solved by adding `'djmoney',` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. When you do this, `MoneyField` will injects correct serializer field for the conversion and all works. HTH :-)

Comment: That's quite a valuable lesson. To always place third party Django apps in INSTALLED_APPS, even if they seem to work without it.